# Delete specific word with all the characters that come after it in the same line and delete the next line as well from text file with python

Tags: python

I want to open the text file in python and delete every line with it's characters that contain the word "Rotana" and delete the line right after it with it's all characters.

So I have several lines in a text file that contain the word "Rotana" and I need to delete this word from my text file with the whole line and it's characters as well the line that comes after it, and here an example:

```
#Rotana title = "Music",
www.fm.com

#Rotana title = "classic",
www.classic.com
```

so I need to delete those from my text file.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal Reproducible Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through and rewrite the file, skipping over the lines you don't want.

```
file = open("FILENAME.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()

file = open("FILENAME.txt", "w")
i = 0
while i < len(lines):
    line = lines[i]
    if "Rotana" not in line:
        file.write(line)
    else:
        i = i + 1
    i = i + 1
file.close()
```

Comment: but what if I want to read the file from down to up and then rewrite it, I thought this would work but it didn't :

`file = open("out.txt", "r",encoding='UTF8')
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()

file = open("out3.txt", "w",encoding='UTF8')
i = len(lines)\n
while i != 0:\n
    line = lines[i]
    if "rotana" not in line:
        file.write(line)
    else:
        i = i - 1
    i = i - 1
file.close()`

Comment: but what if I want to read the file from down to up and then rewrite it, I thought this would work but it didn't :

`file = open("out.txt", "r",encoding='UTF8')`
`lines = file.readlines()`
`file.close()`

`file = open("out3.txt", "w",encoding='UTF8')`
`i = len(lines)`
`while i != 0:`
   `line = lines[i]`
   `if "rotana" not in line:`
       `file.write(line)`
    `else:`
        `i = i - 1`
    `i = i - 1`
`file.close()`

Comment: You need to start your loop at len(lines)-1 and stop when i < 0 if you are running backwards due to zero indexing.

Comment: I didn't understand, can you please show me how

Comment: thank you very much I get it, and my purpose from those tasks is learning

Answer (score 0):

this should work...

```
import re
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open('in.txt', 'r') as f_in, open('out.txt', 'w') as f_out:
        f_out.write(re.sub(r"[^\n]*Rotana([^\n]*\n){,2}", "", f_in.read(), re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL))
```

with `in.txt`:

```
some text here
some more...


whatever #Rotana title = "Music",
www.fm.com
abracadabra
#Rotana title = "classic",
www.classic.com

some text
```

generates `out.txt`:

```
some text here
some more...


abracadabra

some text
```